# Can't upgrade an angular 1.5 component that requires another controller to angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-upgrade

I have two angular 1.5 components: tabs and tab. The tab component requires the controller of tabs component so the latter can manage the active state of the tab components. Here is the code (in typescript):

```
class TabsComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
  public bindings: any;
  public controller: Function;  

  constructor() {
    this.bindings = {
      tabsClass: '@',
      onSelect: '&'
    };
    this.controller = TabsController;
   ...
  }
}

export class TabsController {
...
}

export class TabComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {

  constructor() {
    this.require = {
      parent: '^TabsComponent'
    };
    ...
  }
}


export class TabController  { 
  public $onInit(): void {
    this.parent.addTab(this);
  };
}
```

When I tried to upgrade these two components to angular 2 with UpgradeAdapter, the parent in TabController never gets resolved and I get "undefined doesn't have a function 'addTab'" error message.

Comment: Can you put all code? I try it but I got Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'TabsComponent', required by directive 'tab', can't be found!

Answer (score 0):

Look like it doesn't understand this.parent. I don't really understand your approach but I would specify child components in parent's template.

Comment: The components worked perfectly fine with angular 1.5. It is only with angular 2 are there problems.